# Is there any native method to convert byte array to Hex strings?

Tags: node.js

Say, we have

```
[ 16,
  51,
  172,
  111,
  215,
  161,
  21,
  116,
  19,
  190 ]
```

and want to covert to Hex strings like

`8fa334c..`

Is there any native method implemented to node.js?
If not, what is the common way to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`Buffer`](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) object's [`toString`](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end) method to convert the byte array to a hexadecimal string. From the documentation:

> Converting between Buffers and JavaScript string objects requires an explicit encoding method. Here are the different string encodings.
>
> - 'hex' - Encode each byte as two hexadecimal characters.
>
> ...
>
> #### `buf.toString([encoding], [start], [end])`
>
> Decodes and returns a string from buffer data encoded with encoding (defaults to 'utf8') beginning at start (defaults to 0) and ending at end (defaults to buffer.length).

The following code should work for you:

```
var hexString = new Buffer(arr).toString('hex');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I could not find `new Buffer(arr)` part although knowing toString('hex') which doesn't work itself. I accept your A later.

Comment: Buffer is available in node.js, but not natively in a browser. You might see if https://github.com/feross/buffer works for you. I haven't tried it.